# Combine two files of different lengths into one file

Tags: join, awk

The situation is:

*file_1*

```
7010-1
7010-2
7010-3
```

*file_2*

```
7010,xxx,yyy,7123,01
7010,xxx,yyy,7122,02
7010,xxx,yyy,9101,03
7010,xxx,yyy,7123,01
7010,xxx,yyy,7122,02
7010,xxx,yyy,9101,03
7010,xxx,yyy,7123,01
7010,xxx,yyy,7122,02
7010,xxx,yyy,9101,03
7010,xxx,yyy,7119,04
7010,xxx,yyy,7117,05
7010,xxx,yyy,7112,06
```

*desired output*

```
7010-1,xxx,yyy,7123,01
7010-1,xxx,yyy,7122,02
7010-1,xxx,yyy,9101,03
7010-2,xxx,yyy,7123,01
7010-2,xxx,yyy,7122,02
7010-2,xxx,yyy,9101,03
7010-3,xxx,yyy,7123,01
7010-3,xxx,yyy,7122,02
7010-3,xxx,yyy,9101,03
7010-3,xxx,yyy,7119,04
7010-3,xxx,yyy,7117,05
7010-3,xxx,yyy,7112,06
```

I don't expect `join` to be the right option here, since I don't want the rows be pre-sorted (due to columns 2, 3, 4, and 5), is that correct? Would rather go for `awk`, something like `awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $0; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,h[$1]}' file_1 file_2`. But something is missing. Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Comment: What's the rule for combining?

Comment: I'd say the 1st and the last column. Starting from top of the last column of file_2, when it starts over again counting from 1, we move to the next row of file_1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," }
     { if (!n || $5 < n) { getline id < "file_1" }
       $1=id; print; n=$5 }' file_2
```

Comment: `n` is the value of the previous 5th column. `id` is the line from `file_1`.

Comment: Thank you. So what are the two pipes doing?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help.